Best way to implement the "plus-distribution" for very long expressions?
I'm at my wits end here. Is there an efficient way to implement the following distribution into MMA:
$$\int_0^y dx \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{y-x}$$
where $f/1-x$ can be analytically integrated. The difficulty lies in the fact that I cannot really use the built in Integrate for the following reason:
$f$ is a very long polynomial. Using built in integrate takes forever, cf. Integrate many simple terms fast
So my current workaround for integrals of this sort is:
cIntegrate[f_, t_, t1_, t2_] := Module[{F, func},
   If[ToString@Head[Expand[f]] == "Plus",
    func = Function[{t}, Expand[f]];
    F = Function[{x}, Evaluate[Map[Integrate[#, x] &, func[x]]]];,
    func = Function[{t}, f];
    F = Function[{x}, Evaluate[Integrate[func[x], x]]];
    ];
   Return[F[t2] - F[t1]]
   ];

The problem is, I cannot directly insert $y$ for $t_2$, since it has a pole there. (MMA does not automatically cancel those as far as I have seen.) That means I currently insert something very close to $y$, say $y-10^{-10}$.
But for some reason, I get imaginary parts for the evaluated integral.
Does someone have an alternative on how to evaluate this integral? Fixing the problem with the imaginary parts is also satisfactory
Below you see the explicit code:
AbsoluteTiming[
   u[t_] = ((tf - t0)/2)^2  cIntegrate[(t - t1) Sum[
         ToExpression["a" <> ToString@k] ChebyshevT[k, t1], {k, 0, 
          l}], t1, -1, t] + (initialvalueu - 
       initialderu  t0) + ((tf - t0)/2  t + (tf + t0)/2) initialderu; 
   temp1[t_] = 
    Piecewise[{{2 (cIntegrate[(vertex2[t, t1] u[t1])/(t - t1), t1, -1,
            t - 10^-10] - 
          vertex2[t, t] u[t] Integrate[1/(
            t - t1), {t1, -1, t - 10^-10}, 
            Assumptions -> t > 10^-10 - 1]), t != -1}, {0, 
       t == -1}}];] // Print;

$l=26$ here. vertex2 you can just generate a random numbers for the indices of the following
  Sum[a[i, j] ChebyshevT[i, t1] ChebyshevT[j, t2], {i, 0, l}, {j, 0, 
    l}];

EDIT: I realized where the imaginary part is coming from. If you
Integrate[t1^2/(t-t1),t1,Assumptions->t>t1]

it will output
-(1/2) t1 (2 t + t1) - t^2 Log[-t + t1]

So it actually added a complex constant $i\pi t^2$. Now normally these two complex constants should cancel if you use the same antiderivative and insert two values $<t$. But due to numerical uncertainties, the large coefficients inside the Chebyshev Polynomials actually give order 1 imaginary parts. (the vertex2 has numerical coeff. with finite precision.)
How do I stop MMA from adding complex constants?

Hm. When f[x] is a polynomial, then something tells me that the one-side integral over (f[x]-f[y])/(x-y) can only be evaluated if the factor (y-x) can be cancelled. (Since the integral is one-sided, there is no way to get rid of the 1/z-sigularity by prinicipal value.) So we may try to cancel y-x algebraically by applying Together[Apart[(f[x] - f[y])/(y - x), x]]. Does this work for you?

Oh, since polynomials are always differentiable, (f[x] - f[y])/(y - x) should stay bounded for x converging to y. So, certainly that should work! In theory. The only problem is whether Mathematica can handle your complicated expressions.

@HenrikSchumacher Right, the points of the plus distribution is to use continuity to make sense of 1/|x| as a distribution. I know it can handle limits just fine. Right now, my workaround is to explicitly do a CoefficientList and replace the integrals by the analytical result and inserting something very close to the coincident limit

What I tried to say is that Together[Apart[(f[x] - f[y])/(y - x), x]] will be a polynomial expression, again...

@HenrikSchumacher I'll try, maybe this gives me something a lot more... "smooth" than Beta functions. EDIT: Ok, it takes too long to evaluate

Alternatively, you can try to convert to CoeffientRules and then back with FromCoefficientRules. Maybe that works better.

For the polynomial $f(x) = x^m$ we have
$$\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} x^k y^{m-1-k}$$.
So for a general polynomial $f(x) = \sum_{m = 0}^n a_m x^m$ we have
$$\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} = \sum_{m=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}  a_ m x^k y^{m-1-k}$$.
So I propose to convert your polynomial to monomilas (e.g., with CoeffientRules) and to make the above substitutions. Here an example:
The potentially slow method:
f = x |-> x^6 + 5 x^3 - 1;
Together[Apart[(f[y] - f[x])/(y - x)]]


5 x^2 + x^5 + 5 x y + x^4 y + 5 y^2 + x^3 y^2 + x^2 y^3 + x y^4 + y^5

The potentially faster method:
FromCoefficientRules[
 Join @@ (CoefficientRules[f[x], 
     x] /. {({m_} -> a_) :> 
      Table[{k, m - 1 - k} -> a, {k, 0, m - 1}]}),
 {x, y}
 ]


5 x^2 + x^5 + 5 x y + x^4 y + 5 y^2 + x^3 y^2 + x^2 y^3 + x y^4 + y^5

In fact, you can do also the integration directly with the coeffient rules:
Integrate[
  5 x^2 + x^5 + 5 x y + x^4 y + 5 y^2 + x^3 y^2 + x^2 y^3 + x y^4 + 
   y^5, {x, 0, y}] // Expand


(55 y^3)/6 + (49 y^6)/20

Expand@FromCoefficientRules[
  Join @@ (CoefficientRules[f[x], 
      x] /. {({m_} -> a_) :> 
       Table[{m} -> a/(k + 1), {k, 0, m - 1}]}),
  {y}
  ]


(55 y^3)/6 + (49 y^6)/20


Interesting. I am already replacing the monomials by the integral of $x^n/(y-x)$, but of course this one is even better. I'll try it out.
